# JPA entity inheritance with inherited PostgreSQL's tables

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I use table inheritance in PostgreSQL, table *business* extends *users*.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "service", name = "users")
public class Users {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "nickname")
    private String name;
    private String password;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String id, String password, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Table *business* has column *short_name* that *users* hasn't. When I use this:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "service", name = "business")
public class Business extends Users {
    @Column(name = "short_name")
    private String shortName;
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA tells me that there is no column *short_name* and accepts only *users* table values. How to solve this problem right? Won't it work, or it's only IDEA's problem?

Comment: Please post complete Users class. So far, it compiles normally in NetBeans IDE.

Comment: It compiles normally in IDEA too, it only warnings me of wrong column name short_name.

Comment: Then it's probably something IDEA-specific. How about underlying database tables, are they created and loaded correctly?

Comment: Hm, the problem is deeper than I've expected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841811/postgresql-inheritance-with-jpa-hibernate . JPA doesn't support PostgreSQL's inheritance.