# How to reference a specific line in a PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

My problem is simple:
I have a column referencing people, and among all those persons one and only one has a specific status. What is the best way to represent this in a PostgreSQL database?

My first idea was to create a column of booleans all equal to false but for the specific person. It means I somehow also need to check that there is only one true in the entire column. However, it does not seem optimal as it means having one more bit per column, and as there might be quite a number of lines, it will waste data.
Second solution is to create a second table to reference the person. However it means creating a table just with one line...

Do you have any other idea of how to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with a 1 record table?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was an easier solution I wouldn't have think of! ;)

Comment: I should have said, I can't think of any problem with using a 1 record table, or a better method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL has an [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html) system that may work well for a problem like this.

```
CREATE TABLE people (...);
CREATE TABLE special_person ( ) INHERITS (people);
```

You can `select * from people` to pull *all* of the records, while still adding exclusive columns to the `special_person`.

Comment: This is a nice feature, thanks for bringing this to our awareness. Section "5.8.1. Caveats" is a little painful, I'd also be interested in how ORMs support this feature. I had a read of this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841811/postgresql-inheritance-with-jpa-hibernate which I thought made for good reading.

Comment: It's unlikely that _any_ ORM's directly support the Postgres inheritance model -- but even if your ORM builds your schema for you, inheritance relationships can be established between tables with common columns. As long as your _application_ understands the inheritance structure - when to create an object of the parent or the child, everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a table with one entry, with a foreign key to the main table seems reasonable to me. Having to maintain a status when you only care about one value seems wasteful and comparatively difficult to maintain.