# Which the best way to use inheritance of tables in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i want to use inheritance in my database (PostgreSQL) so i wrote this code but finally i found there are inherits in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.user_account_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE public.user_account (
                id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.user_account_id_seq'),
                login VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                f_name VARCHAR(50),
                l_name VARCHAR(50),
                email VARCHAR(50) ,
                CONSTRAINT user_account_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE public.simple_user_account_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE public.simple_user_account (
                id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.simple_user_account_id_seq'),
                CONSTRAINT simple_user_account_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE public.supervisor_account_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE public.supervisor_account (
                id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.supervisor_account_id_seq'),
                CONSTRAINT supervisor_account_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

with

```
ALTER TABLE public.simple_user_account ADD CONSTRAINT simple_user_account_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES public.user_account (id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE public.supervisor_account ADD CONSTRAINT supervisor_account_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES public.user_account (id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

or i use  **INHERITS** of postgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With inheritance you cannot have globally unique constraints. If that doesn't bother you, you can use the feature.

Comment: Is it compatible with hibernate (in ORM) ?

Comment: But it's doesn't work with hibernate i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841811/postgresql-inheritance-with-jpa-hibernate

Comment: It seems credible that a non-standard feature like inheritance won't work well with Hibernate (which you didn't mention in your question). The connection between "ORM" and "works" is a loose one in general. You are probably best served with a very simple data model.

Comment: That's what i thought .i will accept your answer thank you